# Futurecast or Forecast

Tags: vocabulary

I saw the word "futurecast" in a TV weather report. What is the difference between "futurecast" and "forecast"?

Comment: it's a "made up word" -- a "marketing invention", just as Tommy explains.  There are many, many examples of this in English.  superburger! kneel-chair!  fatdog! (bigger hotdogs!) and so on.

Comment: I agree, it is a made-up word. Why do we make up redundant words? At least "superburger" describes the burger...what does "futurecast" describe? The future forecast? They mean the same thing.

Comment: "Futurecast" is a neologism invented by TV stations and used to refer to weather forecasts.  It presumably is judged to sound more "sexy" and "catchy" than "forecast".  I would strongly advise not using it in any other context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forecast is a prediction of something in the future and is most often used in this context. That said, it appears that futurecast is now synonymous in weather reports; Googling "futurecast" leads to dozens of weather reports. So, my guess is that someone started using this and it caught on and is now acceptable.. though I prefer forecast and "futurecast" is not a word in my dictionary, so its industry specific.